# Access subquery for Distinct Count and Count on same table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Hello I have browsed the forum for a while and am asking my first question here. I'm in a bit of a bind and was wondering if I could get some help out. I am using Access and have not found a good answer to the question on the Net yet.

I have a table called tblTransactions for transactions on Access 2013. It looks like this:

| Transaction_ID | Customer_No | Prod_ID | Lıcence_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 111 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 222 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 111 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 222 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 222 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 333 | 1 | 1 |

tblProd looks like:

| Prod_ID | Prod_Name | Prod_Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Prod 1 | 30 |
| 2 | Prod 2 | 50 |

tblLicence looks like:

| Lıcence_ID | Lıcence_Name | Lıcence_Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lıcence 1 | 80 |
| 2 | Lıcence 2 | 100 |

The customer purchases the product once and may obtain multiple licenses for this product. The product is paid once, but for all licenses owned.

I want to create a summary list for transactions. I cannot print how many different prod it has and how many licenses it has in total next to the customer number.

The output I want should look like this:

| Customer_No | Count_Uniq_Prods | Count_Licences | Sum_Prods_Price | Sum_Licences_Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2 | 3 | 80 | 260 |
| 222 | 2 | 3 | 80 | 280 |
| 333 | 1 | 1 | 30 | 80 |

I tried different methods for the first 3 columns.

1. When I try with subquery, the Customer number and product count are correct, but it also removes duplicates from licenses.

```
SELECT C.Customer_No, T2.Count_Uniq_Prods, T2.Count_Licences" & _
        FROM" & _
            (SELECT T1.Customer_No, T1.Count_Uniq_Prods, Count(Lıcence_ID) As Count_Licences"
            FROM" & _
                (SELECT DISTINCT Customer_No, Lıcence_ID, Count(Prod_ID) As Count_Uniq_Prods
                FROM tblTransactions  GROUP BY Customer_No, Lıcence_ID ) AS T1
            GROUP BY T1.Customer_No, T1.Count_Uniq_Prods) AS T2
        INNER JOIN tblTransactions  AS C
        ON T2.Customer_No = C.Customer_No" & _
        GROUP BY C.Customer_No, T2.Count_Uniq_Prods, T2.Count_Licences;
```

2. When I try the left join operation, I can successfully get results for the product and license separately, but when I want to get it in a single table, the results are not what I want.

It's work for Customer_No, Count_Uniq_Prods,  Sum_Prods_Price:

```
SELECT T.Customer_No,
Count(T.Prod_ID), SUM(tblProd.Prod_Price) AS Sum_Prods_Price
FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT Customer_No, Prod_ID FROM tblTransactions ) AS T
LEFT JOIN tblProd ON tblProd.Prod_ID= T.Prod_ID)
GROUP BY T.Customer_No;
```

It's work for Customer_No, Count_Licences,  Sum_Licences_Price:

```
SELECT T.Customer_No,
Count(T.Lıcence_ID), SUM(tblLicence.[Lıcence_Price]) AS Sum_Licences_Price
FROM ((SELECT Customer_No, Lıcence_ID FROM tblTransactions ) AS T
LEFT JOIN tblLicence ON tblLicence.Lıcence_ID = T.Lıcence_ID)
GROUP BY T.Customer_No
```

But when I take one as a subquery inside the other, I cannot reach the desired result in both results.

I hope I was able to explain clearly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

My approach was to take your problem and break it down into its constituent elements.

> This query retrieves the **products** in the format that you
> requested.

```
select customer_no, count(t.prod_id) as Count_Uniq_Prods, 
       sum(p.prod_price) as Sum_Prods_Price
      from  ( 
         select customer_no, prod_id
         from tblTransactions t
         group by customer_no, prod_id
      ) t
     inner join tblProd p on
       t.prod_id = p.prod_id
     group by customer_no
```

> This query retrieves the **licenses** in the format that you
> requested.

```
select customer_no, count(t. license_id) as Count_Licenses, 
  sum(l.license_price) as Sum_Licenses_Price
from tblTransactions t
inner join tblLicense l on 
  t.license_id = l.license_id
  group by customer_no
```

> Finally,  we put them together and get the following:

```
select distinct  p.customer_no, Count_Uniq_Prods, 
         Count_Licenses,
         Sum_Prods_Price,
         Sum_Licenses_Price         
from (
     select customer_no, count(t.prod_id) as Count_Uniq_Prods, 
       sum(p.prod_price) as Sum_Prods_Price
      from  ( 
         select customer_no, prod_id
         from tblTransactions t
         group by customer_no, prod_id
      ) t
     inner join tblProd p on
       t.prod_id = p.prod_id
     group by customer_no
     
 ) p
inner join (
    select customer_no, count(t. license_id) as Count_Licenses, 
      sum(l.license_price) as Sum_Licenses_Price
    from tblTransactions t
    inner join tblLicense l on 
      t.license_id = l.license_id
      group by customer_no
    ) l
 on p.customer_no = l.customer_no
```

Comment: Yes this is working. Thanks for your effort and help.

In addition, let me make a small addition for those who need it in the future. I had to remove the double quotes while using it.

Comment: @AbdilAka, thanks for pointing that out. I did it for SQL Server.  I will make the required adjustements.